# Proving if $n > m$ then $(n-i)/(m-i)<n/m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I prove, using algebra, that if $n > m$, then: $$\frac{n-i}{m-i}<\frac{n}{m}$$

All I can think of is that $n-i>m-i$ because $n>m$, but I can't link that to the above inequality.

Comment: Are all the variables assumed to be positive?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, n, m, i are all positive integers.

Comment: Then multiply both side by $-i$, and add $mn$. See what happens.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The first step is _not_ justified since $m-i$ can be negative.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 OK, then consider cases where $i<m$ and $i>m$

Comment: So basically, assuming $n > m > i > 0$, the correct version would be the reversed inequality
$$\frac{n-i}{m-i}>\frac{n}{m}$$
Or alternatively, the given inequality 
$$\frac{n-i}{m-i}<\frac{n}{m}$$
holds if $m > n > i > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement if false:

Observe that when $n=4$ and $m=2$, $\frac{n}{m}=2$.  On the other hand, for $i=1$, $\frac{n-i}{m-i}=\frac{3}{1}=3$.

If we wanted to try the inequality $n<m$ and see what happens there, then for $n=1$ and $m=2$ with $i=3$, we get $\frac{n}{m}=\frac{1}{2}$ while $\frac{n-i}{m-i}=\frac{-2}{-1}=2$.

Therefore, there needs to be additional assumptions for the inequality to hold.

Comment: I'm confused now because the lecturer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZHBa-rLrBA&index=8&list=PL8B24C31197EC371C&t=0s) asumed it was correct and can be proven using algebra at 1:11:24.

Comment: In the linked video, there are many many differences from what you asked.  First, the instructor stated that $n<m$.  Also, the only $i$ values that were allowed were up to $i=0,...,m-1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct when $n > m> i > 0$

For example, if $n=3, m=2, i=1$ then $$\frac{n-i}{m-i} = \frac{3-1}{2-1} =2 \not < \frac32 = \frac{n}{m}$$

It is correct when $n>m>0$ and $i>m>0$

The case $i=m$ leads to division by $0$

Answer (score 1):

What's true, with the hypothesis $n>m>i>0$, is that, on the contrary,
$$\frac nm<\frac{n-i}{m-i}$$
Indeed, since all  denominators are positive, it is equivalent to
$$n(m-i)<m(n-i)\iff -ni<-mi \Leftrightarrow n>m\quad(\text{simplifying by }{-i)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement isn’t true.

For instance, say $n = 8$, $m = 6$, and $i = 2$. ($n > m > i > 0$)

$$\frac{8-2}{4-2} = \frac{6}{2} = 3$$
$$3 > \frac{8}{6}$$

This can be shown algebraically too.

$$\frac{n-i}{m-i} < \frac{n}{m}$$
$$m(n-i) < n(m-i)$$
$$mn-im < mn-in$$
$$-im < -in \implies \frac{-im}{-i} > \frac{-in}{-i} \implies m > n$$
This contradicts the original statement. Also, you can simply think of the pattern. For instance, assume $i = 1$.

For $m > n$: $$\frac{4}{5} < \frac{5}{6} < \frac{6}{7} < ...$$
As you subtract $i$ from both the numerator and the denominator, the value decreases.

For $n > m$: $$\frac{7}{6} < \frac{6}{5} < \frac{5}{4} < ...$$
As you subtract $i$ from both the numerator and denominator, the value increases. (Once again contradicting your initial statement.)